# T4MVC: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, t4mvc

I'm trying to use the T4MVC project from the MVCContrib project on codeplex (v2.6.13).
I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM running against .NET 4 in Visual Studio 2010.

Using the Default project template that you get when creating a new MVC 2 Web Application I modified the Home ActionLink in the Master Page to:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Home", MVC.Home.Index()) %>
```

Now I get an HttpException of "Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory" every time I try and browse the project (F5 in VS2010).

If I remove that ActionLink then everything works just fine.

Stack Trace

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.]
>      System.Web.Util.UrlPath.ReduceVirtualPath(String path) +8774912
>      System.Web.Util.UrlPath.Reduce(String path) +52
>      System.Web.Util.UrlPath.Combine(String appPath, String basepath, String relative) +217
>      System.Web.UI.Control.ResolveClientUrl(String relativeUrl) +258
>      System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink.RenderAttributes(HtmlTextWriter writer) +74
>      System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +42
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +208
>      System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +21
>      System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +31
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>      ASP.views_shared_site_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\82809071\51b73fea\App_Web_uers1hdy.1.cs:0
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +109
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
>      System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +208
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
>      System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +56
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3060

I've been banging my head on this for a while now but I don't seem to be able to find anything in the documentation or related blogs that might point to the solution.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, I can't make sense of that.  Where exactly in the .master did you put that code?  The stack seems to say that the error comes when rendering the <head> tag, but in the default template that's not where the link is.

Comment: You ever figure this out?